# How to add GA Transaction after Paypal IPN

Tags: php, javascript, paypal, google-analytics, paypal-ipn

From the listener PHP file, is it possible to add transactions to GA via JavaScript? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your only using a listener file for the response, or plan on using a redirect, then this won't be possible. It is however very feasible to save the `hash` as a `$_SESSION` that is returned from paypal, and then on your "receipt" page drop in the GA/conversion tracking.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Problem is if the customer doesn't return to the receipt page. I can't choose to auto-redirect from Paypal after transaction right?